# design of a list to horizontal

Tags: html, angular, css

I want to change the view of a website from a vertical list to horizontal. 
Every change I did hide my data. 
How can I do it?
css:

```
img {
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: powderblue;
}
ul{

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;

}
li{
    margin-right: 0px;
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 16px;
text-decoration: none;}
```

html:

```
    <h2>store</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let store of stores">

    <h4>Products:</h4>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let product of store.Products">
          <img src={{product.ProductImage}}>
          <p>store: {{ store.StoreName }}</p>
          <p>Product Price: {{ product.Price }}</p>
        <p>Product Title: {{ product.ProductTitle }}</p>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the look of the website:[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IZmi.png)

Comment: Do you mean to want to scroll sideways? Or just display items next to each other where there is space?

Comment: items next to each other simpley. display: inline-block ;
it changes some but like: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sBx8.png) nicer way? thanks!

Comment: Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Try to give li display: inline-block; and width: to some specific as you have given to the img tag and p to word-break: break-all;

Comment: Have you looked at flexbox, which gives you a high level of flexibility re this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox, give the ul after Products header this style **display: flex** and remove that **overflow: hidden** from your ul in css. Default direction in flex is **row**, if you want to change it to a column, just add **flex-direction: column;**

```
<h2>store</h2>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let store of stores">

    <h4>Products:</h4>
    **<ul style="display:flex">**
      <li *ngFor="let product of store.Products">
          <img src={{product.ProductImage}}>
          <p>store: {{ store.StoreName }}</p>
          <p>Product Price: {{ product.Price }}</p>
        <p>Product Title: {{ product.ProductTitle }}</p>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```